# Why is it not the FBI's policy to electronically record witness interviews?

Tags: recording, witnesses, fbi, interrogation, crime

What I *think* is the reason is related to Title 18 of the United States Code, section 1001, which makes it a felony for anyone to make a false statement to the FBI. This, in turn, means that if there's no verbatim record the witness actually said, whatever words the agent deigns to write in the 302 (a record created by the agent's notes. Not signed by the witness.) become, in effect, the witness' words. As do the omissions. The witness can never contradict anything that the agent writes (or chooses not to write) in the 302 without facing the threat of felony charges under section 1001.

Comment: Are you expecting FBI policies to be regulated by law?

Comment: Wait, why do you expect that the FBI is above the law?

Comment: @user6726 I don't, but I do expect that the law won't micromanage individual agencies' policies, and that whether to record interviews would be a matter of discretion of the policy maker (vs. the law makers).

Comment: @Greendrake the law, even if written in rather general terms, should set such a framework that would not allow let alone encourage abuse of power. The Founding Fathers presumed even the President and the Justices to be as fallible as anyone. There is no reason not to have such laws in place — other one driven by The Rules of the Justice Game — to not allow for such policies that would result in the above pictures scenario. Justice is more important than aesthetics and looks about “micro management” — especially in such dire matters where this agency has to step in.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because *why* a policy is the way that it is is a political question.

Answer (score 1):

You are speaking of former policy, which changed. The policy and underlying reasons are discussed [here](https://harvardlawreview.org/2015/03/dept-of-justice-new-department-policy-concerning-electronic-recording-of-statements/) and [here](https://thehill.com/opinion/criminal-justice/498694-why-the-fbi-doesnt-record-interviews?rl=1). The reasons are practical and not legal, having to do with logistical burden, interference with rapport building, and misinterpretation by juries and judges regarding (im)proper interviewing techniques. But as of July 11, 2014 the presumption is that custodial interviews will be recorded, with articulated exceptions. This is about custodial interviews, so there is no general assumption that *all* interviews will be recorded (*nobody* has that requirement, and the number of informal non-custodial interviews carried out by LEOs vastly exceeds the number of custodial interviews).